# How to move row to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA is a total black magic to me so please be gentle and assume you're talking to an idiot :)

I've created a spreadsheet, with multiple tabs.
Based on a drop down selection, I am trying to move rows to corresponding sheets.

I've achieved that ( and is working great ) by using the below VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'   Check to see only one cell updated
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column C after row 7 and is set to "Yes"
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row > 7 And (Target.Value = "LTS" Or Target.Value = "On Hold") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns A to AU to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "AU")).Copy Sheets("On Hold and LTS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column C after row 7 and is set to "Yes"
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row > 7 And (Target.Value = "Leaver") Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns B to I to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "AU")).Copy Sheets("Leavers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Although the above code works as intended, every time I receive the "run time error 424 - object required message". Clicking end resolves it and the rule works as intended.

( The second part of the code [ Leaver ] does not produce the error, and also works as intended )

Could you please help me stopping this error from coming up please?

Thank you!

Comment: Which row throws that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cell contains "LTS" (or "On Hold") then the first `If..End If` block runs and among other things deletes the row containing `Target`. You then move to your second `If..End If` block and test `Target` - which no longer exists - hence your error.

Try using ElseIf in there instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'   Check to see only one cell updated
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column C after row 7 and is set to "Yes"
    If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row > 7 And (Target.Value = "LTS" Or Target.Value = "On Hold") Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns A to AU to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "AU")).Copy Sheets("On Hold and LTS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column C after row 7 and is set to "Yes"
    ElseIf Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row > 7 And (Target.Value = "Leaver") Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns B to I to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "AU")).Copy Sheets("Leavers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OP states the error occurs at the first block and the second block works without the error.

Comment: I think the OP has confused [testing the first block causes the error] with [the error occurs within the first block]. Entering LTS is to test the first block, but will cause the second block *test* to error due to the first block already having run.

Comment: This is why I asked for the line that throws the error - but OP seems to be confident that we can guess by our own...